# Turn off variable declaration in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Is there any way to make Perl 6 not require `my` to declare variables?  I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6
no strict;
no warnings;

$z = "hello world";
say $z;
```

But that didn't work

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ./helloworld.pl
Variable '$z' is not declared
at ./helloworld.pl:5
------> $z⏏ = "hello world";
    expecting any of:
        postfix
```

EDIT: This is a bug in Rakudo.  See Perl 6 spec: http://design.perl6.org/S01.html The official Rakudo package appears to go out of date very quickly.  It is recommended that you compile from source: http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/

Comment: Works in my Rakudo; you presumably have an older version.

Comment: The warnings machinery works but the pragma hasn't yet been implemented.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

`no strict;` got implemented in October 2014.

See: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/docs/ChangeLog#L547

There is no `no warnings;` though, as there are not many warnings emitted anyway.
Mostly things are considered either correct or an error. Only rarely do we decide to make something warn.

Comment: Please note that if you do get warnings that you don't want to be visible, you can use a `quietly`; `my $a; $a = $a + 1` would warn with: `Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context`, but `my $a; quietly $a = $a + 1` would not.